# Changing a project from Ruby on Rails to JRuby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-applications, jruby

What do I need to modify to change my ordinary Ruby on Rails project into a JRuby on Rails project? In addition, is it likely that a gem I included in my RoR project will be broken in the JRuby version of my project?

Lastly is there any way to create a JRuby on Rails app in APTANA or any other editor?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to switch to Jruby instead of Ruby and this could be done using RVM. (www.beginrescueend.com)

You will have problems with gem compatibility when you switch to jruby not all gems will work. Usually gems with C extensions.

Lastly, for an IDE I am sure aptana is fine. You are still writing ruby code. Just when you run your code you will be using the JVM.

Comment: do you know ow to create Jruby on Rails project in Aptana? What are the different steps required?

Comment: I personally don't use Aptana. For my rails projects I use Vim(which isn't for everyone). Before that I used Sublime Text or Textmate and both of those IDE's work great for Rails.

Answer (score 0):

The main advantage of jruby instead of normal ruby is we can call the java libraries. And if you want you can even use Hibernate.

And switching if you are on a windows machine you need to use PIK(RVM for windows).

Like ericraio said there may be some gem dependency but most of the time the bundler will take care of that, so you don't need to worry about things(Most of the time).
If you want to check a particular gem please visit this site http://rubygems.org/

For my development I'm using NetBeans 6.9.1. If you want any help regarding how to make you first program in netbeans I'm ready to help.

I prefer to use command prompt to create and run rails project